Why "No errors!" from Hegel when there's a JS file with errors in it?
I'm following the steps on Hegel's website but it's saying "No errors!" even when there's a JS file in the same directory with an error in it that's picked up by the online Hegel playground.

FYI Hegel was archived this year and will see no more development.

Do you happen to know of any other tools that can detect the error I linked to?
